# Finding the joint probability density function of two random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Given
$$ Y_1 = X_1 - X_2 , Y_2 = X_1 + X_2, $$
how can I find the joint probability density function of $$(Y_1,Y_2)?$$

The $X$'s are independent normal random variables and both $Y$'s are random variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use transformations.

$$ Y1 = X1 - X2 = u_1(x_1,x_2)$$
$$ Y2 = X1 + X2 = u_2(x_1,x_2)$$
$$ X_1 = \frac{Y_1+Y_2}{2}=w_1(y_1,y_2)$$
$$ X_2 = \frac{Y_1-Y_2}{2}=w_2(y_1,y_2)$$

$$ f(y_1,y_2) = f(w_1(y1, y2),w_2(y1,y2)|J|$$

j is jaconian

I solved same problem with standard normal distributions.
I added picture of my process.
or You can solve this problem by using distribution method.

good luck :)

[image]